# How to add a hide button to XFce panels?

Tags: xfce, panel

In older versions of GNOME, one could create a panel with arrows at the end, that when clicked, would make the panel disappear.

Is there a way to add a hide button to XFce panels?

Comment: you ask a lot of question about xfce. Try [here](https://forum.xfce.org/)

Comment: are the arrows supposed to remain visible when he panel is hidden?

Comment: My answer below should provide the solution you are looking for. If someone takes the time to post an answer to your question, please show consideration and take the time to interact or respond in some way. Let the person answering know if their answer works or not. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Launch Xfce4 Panel Preferences. Under Items add a custom Launcher (the top option). Edit the launcher by clicking on the gear icon. Then click on the blank sheet with a plus button. Next add the following next to Command:.

`bash -c 'display_hide () { xfconf-query -c xfce4-panel -p /panels/panel-1/autohide-behavior $1 $2; }; [[ $(display_hide) == 2 ]] && display_hide -s 0 || display_hide -s 2'`

Replace `panel-1` with the number of the panel you are toggling. Under Display in Panel Preferences, you will have to change the 'Automatically hide the panel:' setting one time beforehand. Otherwise it will throw an error that the Property does not exist.